Seeking simplest examples for booleans from etoolbox to LaTeX3
I am struggling with making a clean transition to LaTeX3 syntax, specifically for boolean constructions. I have already implemented the move from the ifthen package to the etoolbox package. What I miss is the simplest of examples to make the next step. I would appreciate taking this MWE to a LaTeX3 level.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{eifthen}
\setbool{eifthen}{true}

\newcommand{\doit}{%
    \ifbool{eifthen}%
    {It's TRUE, it's true, it's really true!}
    {Oh well. Try again later.}
    }

\begin{document}

At this point, we should say: \doit{}

\boolfalse{eifthen}

And here we should say: \doit{} 

\end{document}

My larger need is constructing a template document for users. I intend to have a Document Inputs.tex file with a set of booleans. Users will do the equivalent of \boolfalse or \booltrue setups in the inputs file. My template will construct an output based on their changes. Finally, I appreciate that I can continue to use what I have mastered with etoolbox constructions (and will certainly allow users to do so if they desire). As such, call this an itch to fulfill a nagging academic curiosity.

Why do you want to use expl3?

the question seems confused, you could move from etoolbox to expl3, but you seem to be wanting to use etoolbox so not use expl3 at all.

Academic curiosity. When the move is for a case as simple as what I have posted is simply not worth the effort (as I might infer reading perhaps inappropriately between the spaces in your replies), I will keep to what I know with etoolbox. Trusting of course that etoolbox will not disappear in my remaining professional lifetime. Perhaps then a simple example showing the complexity in the transition will in itself be a good lesson in the trade-offs. IOW, don't do this translation simply for fun in such a simple case.

No I do not understand what you are asking, the title suggests you are asking how to switch from etoolbox to expl3, but the body of the question says " I realize the need to move from the ifthen package to the etoolbox package." ie asking how to switch to etoolbox,. You could ask either question, but I can not guess which you are asking here?

@DavidCarlisle Fixed ... I want to switch from etoolbox to LaTeX3.

@JeffreyJWeimer then do what Ulrike says (always a good idea:-)

Writing your example with expl3 commands is quite easy. But it isn't imho the best for commands on the document level as you have to switch in and out of expl3 and use ~ to get spaces:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N\l_jeff_eif_bool
\bool_set_true:N \l_jeff_eif_bool

\newcommand{\doit}
  {
    \bool_if:NTF\l_jeff_eif_bool
    {It's~TRUE,~it's~true,~it's~really~true!}
    {Oh~well.~Try~again~later.}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

At this point, we should say: \doit{}

\ExplSyntaxOn \bool_set_false:N \l_jeff_eif_bool \ExplSyntaxOff

And here we should say: \doit{} 

\end{document}



Ugh! Lesson learned. I appreciate now why I should go back to expanding my understanding of python to do data analysis in my discipline before I step further into mucking about in the programming levels of LaTeX3, even after 30+ years in the latter versus only 4+ years in the former. Thank you!!

It's not clear if you are asking how to switch from ifthen package to etoolbox or to switch from etoolbox to expl3.
For top level document booleans I probably would not use any of these and simply use
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifethen
\ethentrue

\newcommand{\doit}{%
    \ifethen
      {It's TRUE, it's true, it's really true!}%
    \else     
      {Oh well. Try again later.}%
    \fi
    }

\begin{document}

At this point, we should say: \doit{}

\ethenfalse

And here we should say: \doit{} 

\end{document}


I appreciate this answer. However, despite the likely overhead, I want to stay closer to LaTeX than TeX. Also, instructing beginner level LaTeX users of the template package to do \setboolean{ethen}{true} versus \setbool{ethen}{false} in the Document Settings file is more intuitive than instructing them to choose between \ethenfalse versus \ethentrue.

@JeffreyJWeimer wouldn't a key-value syntax be easier in that case? then you can do the setup in expl3 if you want and just provide a single wrapper command for the document level? or just use \DeclareKeys and not worry about expl3 syntax at all?

Duly noted. I use a LaTeX3 key-value syntax for such things as title, committee member names, and others (and I much appreciate the newest implementations of key-value commands that allow me to avoid doing ExplSyntaxOn/Off coding on my own). Until I get my head clear on using this same approach for booleans, I will stick with etoolbox. Otherwise ... I accepted Ulrike's answer because it goes to the core of my (and perhaps other's) simplest needs. I greatly appreciate hearing from both of you as well-respected masters in this field.

@JeffreyJWeimer David,sure, but not me!

@JeffreyJWeimer for your first comment I probably wouldn't do either in a document command but have a custom command that means something in the context and can be defined to be \ethentrue or  \setboolean{ethen}{true} or \bool_set_false:N \l_jeff_eif_bool  leaving the implementation details to the implementation (but no objection to you accepting Ulrike's which unlike mine does answer your question:-)
